# Использование слова "один" до 1910-ых годов

Tags: история-языка, числительные

Как можно видеть из графика в [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%2C%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%2C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%2C%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B8%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B5%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0), все числительные использовались с примерно постоянной частотой с 1800 года. Но слово *один* до 1910 года практически не встречается в литературе. В то же время слова *одна*, *одно* и *одного* использовались достаточно широко. При этом начало роста частоты использования слова *один* совпадает с ростом частоты использования слова *раз*.

Мне это кажется довольно странным. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать слово "одинъ". (И "разъ" заодно,)

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, теперь понятно. Я пробовал *еден*, а про *одинъ* не подумал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С [дореволюционной орфографией](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=25&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%AA%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%AA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%AA%3B%2Cc0%3B%3B%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8A%3B%2Cc0).